# MobileFirst Version Mismatch

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

> FWLSE3210W: Environment: android of application BBQ version 1.0 has
>   been deployed with a different version of the native MobileFirst SDK.
>   Direct updates will no longer be available for existing clients with
>   other versions of the MobileFirst SDK. To continue to use direct
>   updates, increment the app version, publish it to the public app
>   store, deploy to the server, and (optionally) block/notify older
>   versions of the app to enforce customers to upgrade to the new version
>   from the app store.

I am seeing the above warning again and again. And it doesnt seem to be related to the version difference between my worklight studio and worklight server.

1. I have created a MobileFirst Project in MobileFirst 6.3.
2. I have a remote MobileFirst 6.3 server.

When I deploy the iphone wlapp file first through the worklight console it goes through successfully but when I deploy the android wlapp file of the same app, it shows me the above warning and similar thing happens when I upload the android wlapp file first no issue but when iphone wlapp file is uploaded it shows the warning. Could someone tell me what this warning really is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a false-positive warning message that you can safely ignore.

If you'd like it gone you can also download the latest MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 iFix from IBM Fix Central where it has been fixed.

Comment: what fix we need to download as this warning eventually leads to this error while making adapter call `SRVE0190E: File not found: /authorization/v1/clients/instance`

Comment: There is no relation between the message in this question to yours.

Comment: looks like 71 still gets this "false" positive sometimes